# Why the name Eggs McLaren?

Tags: discussion, display-names, sock-puppets, jeff-atwood

As you might know, [this puppet account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren) asked [the first non-deleted question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4/3151675) and is present on other SE sites as well.

I'm just curious what does the name mean and why that name was chosen (presumably by Jeff Atwood).

Comment: thinking about creating an account with info _This is a puppet test account I use to validate "regular user" stuff on the site - Joel Spolsky_

Answer (score 11):

Maybe the name was chosen because [The McLaren F1's Owner's Manual Is Full Of Awesome Easter Eggs](https://jalopnik.com/the-mclaren-f1s-owners-manual-is-full-of-awesome-easter-1647184396).

YouTube example: [How To Activate The Easter Egg In The McLaren 720S Exhaust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=witGAZDbPCo)